# If Statement -match or -contains not returning correct condition

Tags: powershell, if-statement, match, conditional-statements, statements

We are updating our SIP for email addresses and we are going to use a PowerShell script to monitor when AD is updated and then update the local machine.

I'm to the part where I split the email address at the `@` symbol and I'm looking to the left of the `@` symbol.

Example:

```
FirstName.LastName@someplace.com
```

I can split it correctly where I just get

```
FirstName.LastName
```

but when I go to check the condition if it contains a `.`, I can't get a correct true of false.

Example:

```
$sipaddress = "FirstName.LastName@someplace.com"
$splitname = $sipaddress.Split("@")[0]

# at this point, $splitname varible will contain "FirstName.LastName"

if ($splitname -match '.') {
  Write-Host "TRUE"
} else {
  Write-Host "False"
}

# this returns TRUE which is perfect
```

BUT, if I change the variable to like this for testing

```
$sipaddress = "FirstNameLastName@someplace.com"
```

the `$splitname` variable will contain `FirstNameLastName`, and it still returns TRUE when that is not correct.  It should return false because there is no `.`.

What am I doing wrong?  I tried to use `-contains` in the `if` statement but that does not work either.

Is there a way to try and check for a `-match` for the `.`?

Comment: `-match '\.'` or `-like '*.*'`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to remember this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The [`-match` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) does a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) match, so matching `.` will match any character except newlines, not just dots. If you want to match a literal dot you need to escape it (`\.`) or do a different kind of comparison, for instance a wildcard match with the `-like` operator (`-like '*.*'`) or by using the `Contains()` method of the string object.

The `-contains` operator checks if an array contains a particular element. To be able to use that operator you'd need to convert your string to a character array:

```
[char[]]$splitname -contains '.'
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this, though. The other methods are more convenient.

Modified code:

```
$sipaddress = "FirstName.LastName@someplace.com"

$localpart, $domain = $sipaddress -split '@'

if ($localpart.Contains('.')) {
  Write-Host 'True'
} else {
  Write-Host 'False'
}
```